# EditBox inside StringGrid

Tags: c++builder, tstringgrid, editbox

I have problem with inserting Editbox in StringGrid. I have one StringGrid and one Editbox on my form. The editbox shows just fine in the selected col and row but i can insert just one number in the selected cell... can anyone explain me how to put more numbers in there?

tnx!

```
//Editbox on change event
void __fastcall TForm3::StringGridEditChange(TObject *Sender)
{
    int x,y;

    x = Form3->VariableGrid->Col;
    y = Form3->VariableGrid->Row;

  if (VariableGrid->Col !=2 )
  {
    VariableGrid->Col = 2;
  }
  if (VariableGrid->Row <1 )
  {
    VariableGrid->Row = 1;
    ShowMessage("Prevention!");
  }

  VariableGrid->Cells[VariableGrid->Col][VariableGrid->Row] = StringGridEdit->Text;
  StringGridEdit->Visible = false;
  VariableGrid->SetFocus();

//StringGrid on selectCell event
void __fastcall TForm3::VariableGridSelectCell(TObject *Sender, int ACol, int ARow,
          bool &CanSelect)
{
    if(ACol == 2 && ARow>0)
  {
    TRect R = VariableGrid->CellRect(ACol, ARow);
    R.Left   += VariableGrid->Left;
    R.Right  += VariableGrid->Left;
    R.Top    += VariableGrid->Top;
    R.Bottom += VariableGrid->Top;
    StringGridEdit->Left = R.Left + 1;
    StringGridEdit->Top = R.Top + 1;
    StringGridEdit->Width = (R.Right + 1) - R.Left;
    StringGridEdit->Height = (R.Bottom + 1) - R.Top;
    //Show the editbox
    StringGridEdit->Visible = true;
    StringGridEdit->SetFocus();
  }
  CanSelect = true;
}
```

in C++ Builder XE2

Comment: Why are using a separate Edit control and not the StringGrid's built-in editor? I told you that in your last question.

Comment: You can only enter 1 character because you are hiding the Edit as soon as its Text changes. If you must use a separate Edit then the `OnExit` event would make more sense to use instead of the `OnChange` event.

Comment: please place you solution as an answer here